# MVC4 - Login box within Layout page using Partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a layout page, and want it to have a Login Box, OR display the logged in user, along with a Logout link.

At the moment, my SiteLayout.cshtml file has this:

```
<body>

    <h1>Basic Finance</h1>

    <div>
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @Html.ViewBag.UserDisplay
            @Html.ActionLink("[Logout]", "LogoutUser", "User")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Login")
        }
        <hr />
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, i my Views/Shared/, I have the _Login.cshtml file:

@model BasicFinanceUI.Models.LoginModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Username: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username) 
        Password: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password) 
        Remember Me: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RememberMe, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "No", Value = "false"}
                }, "Select")

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </p>

}
```

This code was moved from a standard view. I had it then there was simply a 'Login' link, instead of the login box in the Layout page. I want to display a login box instead.

My login code is still in a controller I created called 'UserController'. But, I have no idea how to tell my login box to use that controller. Is this the right way to do what I want (or should there be a controller for my login partial). Is it OK to use my 'UserController'? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

**Change:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Username: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username) 
        Password: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password) 
        Remember Me: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RememberMe, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "No", Value = "false"}
                }, "Select")

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </p>

}
```

**To:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Username: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username) 
        Password: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password) 
        Remember Me: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RememberMe, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "No", Value = "false"}
                }, "Select")

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </p>

}
```

Where `"User"` is your controller and `"Login"` is your action method that handles the Login's `POST`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Yes, it's how you specify the route a particular form's post should utilize -- especially in scenarios where a form is in a partial/shared view.